# Vue library typings

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm

I'm making a Vue library as an NPM package which is intented to be used by other projects.

The entry point is `main.ts`, which exposes a plugin and some functions that I commonly use. A simplified example of `main.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Button from '@/components/button.vue'

const myPlugin = {
  install (vue: typeof Vue): void {
    vue.component('the-button', Button)
  }
}

function someFunction(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b
}

export { myPlugin, someFunction }
```

I build the project using `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLibrary src/main.ts`.

Now to my question; how to specify and/or generate typings correctly? As far as I can see, there are two options:

1. Set `"typings": "src/main.ts"` in my `package.json` and use the .ts files themselves as type references. Seems to work but I haven't seen any examples of this being used so I assume it's bad practice?
2. Set `"declaration": true` and `"outDir": "types"` in my `.tsconfig.json`. Along with [some tweaking](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1081) in `vue.config.js` typings seems to be generated correctly, which I would specify with `"typings": "types/main.d.ts"` in the package.json file. Is this the preferred approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the second approach, or better, for my packages I use the second approach.

For [rotating-file-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream), which is not a Vue library, but a TypeScript package anyway, I'm using the said method, that let you to distribute (in the npm package) only the `.js` and the `.d.ts` files which makes the package a bit lighter. The original `.ts` files are always available on github for reference/documentation.